# Why does current/shell directory change depending whether drive-letter is used in filename?

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell

Using VIM (v6.3) from a command-prompt (i.e. not gVIM) I'm getting different behaviour for the `:shell` command depending on whether I specify a drive-letter when editing a file or not.

**Without Driver Letter**

```
X:\>vi Directory\File.txt
```

(file opens; use `:sh` to open a command-prompt)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.379]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

X:\>
```

**With Driver Letter**

```
X:\>vi X:\Directory\File.txt
```

(file opens; use `:sh` to open a command-prompt)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.379]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

X:\Directory>
```

In both cases, I'm editing the same file (`X:\Directory\File.txt`), from the same location (`X:`) but if I don't specify the drive-letter I'm left in the original directory (what I want) whereas if I *do* specify the driver letter I'm left in the directory containing the file being edited.

Does anyone know **(a)** why this is happening, and **(b)** how to stop it? Ideally I'd like to be left in `X:\` in both the above cases. Tested on both Windows 7 and Windows 10.

---

This also seems to affect the expansion of `%` ("the current filename") when executing a shell command. When the drive-letter is given, and the shell opens in the directory containing the file being edited, `%` expands to just the name of the file (`File.txt`). Without the driver-letter, `%` expands to the path as entered when starting VI (`Directory\File.txt`). However, I can handle this by using `%:p` which in both cases expands to the full drive/path/name (`Directory\File.txt`).

Answer (score 1):

I can't say why it happens - I've reproduced the behaviour and it is strange indeed - but here is a work-around I found:

```
vi -c "cd %CD%" X:\Directory\File.txt
```

With `-c`, vi will execute the `cd` command as soon as it opens, taking you back to the working directory you launched vi from.

Caveat: when I'm at C:\ (rather than c:\some-other-dir), I get an error message as vi starts, but the working directory is set correctly despite that error message.

Comment: As you say, this sort of works, unless you're in the root directory. This seems to be because in the root, `%CD%` returns `X:\` but in a directory it returns `X:\Directory` (without a trailing backslash) and VI seems to treat `...\"` as an escape of the double-quote.